# how can I make transition effect

Tags: html, css, transition

I need help for `transition` effect. I have code block and I want to add hover `transition` effect. How can I do it?

```css
.mockup img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mockup img:last-child {
  display: none;
}

.mockup:hover img:first-child {
  display: none;
}

.mockup:hover img:last-child {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto mockup">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-640-480-9.jpg">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-640-480-7.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't transition `display`, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Any idea guys? ??

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I want to change animation speed when mouse hovers on picture. I mean it should be visible slowly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transitions on the display: property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-property)

Comment: If you want to fade between two images, use only the `opacity` property. Ignore the `visibility` in the linked question's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot add transition to display property, but you can replace it with opacity or visibility

So your code can be replaced with:

```
.mockup img {
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.mockup img:last-child {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.mockup:hover img:first-child {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.mockup:hover img:last-child {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but not suitable for me. Also doesn't work

Comment: @atomant Then you should explain better what you want. If Mohamed's answer won't do if for you, and none of the dozens of answers to the linked question apply to your problem, then obviously your problem is different than we think.